# Multiple OR for objects? "If TypeOf control is ComboBox or TextBox" etc

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to coding and VB.net. Just wondering if there is a better way to do the below:

```
If TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox Or TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
' code here
End If
```

Can you do something like:

```
If TypeOf ctl is ComboBox or TextBox or... then

End If
```

Comment: Did you try that?  What happened?  if you use `OrElse` it will stop evaluating conditions when it hits the first match.

Comment: Yea, visual studio says "TextBox is a class type and cannot be used as an expression". And I can't do "or Is". I know there has to be a way, but not sure what it is. My workaround was doing a type array and saying TypeArray.contains(ctl.gettype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a select case statement

```
    Select Case ctl.GetType
        Case GetType(Button), GetType(PictureBox)
           .... whatever
        Case GetType(Label)
           .... whatever
    End Select
```

**ALTERNATIVE ANSWER**

Using a quick array will also work.

```
If {GetType(Button), GetType(PictureBox)}.Contains(ctl.GetType) Then
```

Comment: Thanks! Yea I was thinking this, but I was hoping there was a shorter way, and the different cases really didn't matter to me, just wanted to say if it was 3 certain types then get the name. I ended up just making an array of types and saying if the array contains the type then output name.